# How to reposition a misplaced cursor/blinker in the textarea?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where the cursor/blinker is right in the top left of the textarea with no margin or whatsoever. I don't know what could be causing this, the other inputs are working fine. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

I also wanna know how to change that black border color? I would like the border to stay the same when I click on it. I tried using textarea:focus to get rid of it but it's not working.

Lastly I wanna get rid of this whitish background when a form gets auto-completed, I haven't figured out how to get rid:

[image]

HTML:

```
<form class="form appear appear-hidden" method="post">
    <h1>Contact Me</h1>
    <div class="name-section">
      <input type="name" placeholder="Name" required />
      <input type="surname" placeholder="Surname" required />
    </div>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required />

    <textarea
      class="message"
      type="message"
      placeholder="Message"
      row="4"
      required
    ></textarea>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" placeholder="submit" />
  </form>
```

CSS:

```
.name-section input {
   width: 48%;
   margin: 5px;
   border: 2px solid white;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: transparent;
   font-weight: 600;
}

form input {
   width: 98%;
   margin: 5px;
   border: 2px solid white;
   padding: 10px;
   /* background-color: #000; */
   background-color: transparent;
   font-weight: 600;
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 }

 input::placeholder {
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   color: white;
   font-weight: 600;
 }

 input:focus {
   border: 1px solid white;
 }

 textarea {
   min-height: 100px;
   background-color: transparent;
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   width: 98%;
   margin: 5px;
   border: 2px solid white;
   resize: none;
   font-weight: 600;
 }

 textarea::placeholder {
   color: white;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
   font-weight: 600;
 }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have no padding in your Textaria, try this: remove padding from `textarea::placeholder` and add padding to `.message` :

```
 textarea::placeholder {
   margin: 10px;
   font-weight: 600;
 }
 .message{
  padding:10px;

 }
```

To remove the "black-border-color:

```
input:focus{
     outline:solid 3px blue;
}
```

I didn't understand what you mean by this: "Lastly I wanna get rid of this whitish background when a form gets auto-completed, I haven't figured out how to get rid:"

Comment: I should have picked that up... Thank you, that solved the padding issue in the textarea...

Comment: Do you have any pointers for my others issues I mentioned?

Comment: tomorrow (if nobody helped you) ;)

Comment: Oh okay cool man...